# Error when installing ROS Noetic. 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

Tags: ros

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease                       
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease        
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Im getting this error when installing ROS on my Dell XPS 13. Im new to all of this so any help is appreciated. I other solutions but they work.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's your OS? which installation commands have you executed?

Comment: I have 20.04 and im using this wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

Comment: This error happens when i try to update using ```sudo apt update```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on my ubuntu 20.04 following the same link. Did you execute the commands as suggested in the link "If you experience issues connecting to the keyserver, you can try substituting hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 or hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 in the previous command."?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with the `gnome-terminator` ppa. Try disabling it.